# how to make the mypy accept List[Optional[str]] as input arg for filter()?

Tags: python-3.x

I have these lines:

```
tags: List[Optional[str]] = [None, "adf"]
x: List[str] = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, tags))
```

the mypy errors out `Argument 2 to "filter" has incompatible type "List[Optional[str]]"; expected "Iterable[str]"` Is there anyway to type hint the lambda?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue and the workaround I used was to basically do a list comprehension to remove `None`, which in your case would be

```py
x: List[str] = [t for t in tags if t is not None]
```

I know it's a little bit less pythonic and less readable than the filter approach you were trying to use, but it seems like this is what mypy would prefer.